# How many student are there in school given the following conditions?

Tags: percentages

> In school there are more than 501 student,they play cricket and hockey, exactly 20% play hockey and exactly 28% play cricket. How many student are there in school?

Option

1. $550$
2. $600$
3. $700$
4. None of these

Ans d)

My approach:

I am not able to solve this problem because i think information is not sufficient as I need more quantities.So,from my point of you Ans is d)

> Is there any approach through which you can solve the problem to verify the Ans.

Comment: I also think that there is not sufficient info. Also, the English isn't that great either...

Comment: As long as the number of students is a multiple of 25 greater than 500. you will have an answer because for each 25 students you can make 5 play hockey and 7 play cricket and this will give you a solution. So all of (1),(2),(3) are possible answers. If they want to know the LEAST number of students out of the given options, then it would be (1) 550. Or perhaps (4) because the true minimum greater than 501 is 525.

Comment: @user2566092 How do you know "no of students is multiple of 25"Do you mean when we divide $550$/$25$$600$/$25$,$700$/$25$ .they all are divisible by $25$.Also how did you find 25?